# How to change field of checkbox in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs

I want to change field of checkbox. 
For Example default it is tick sign on check and blank on unchecked.
But i need check sign (✔) on checked and wrong sign (x) on unchecked.

Comment: What have you tried? What worked, and what didn't? We prefer to help with specific problems. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: What version of Ext are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with this small and simple CSS. The solution varies slightly depending on your theme, but e.g. in ExtJS 6 Triton:

```
.x-grid-checkcolumn-checked:before {
 content:"\f05d"
}

.x-grid-checkcolumn:before {
 content:"\f05c"
}
```

This would change ALL your check columns, if you need certain columns styled like this, use a specific userCls on the columns:

```
xtype:'checkcolumn',
userCls:'myCls',
```

with the CSS

```
.myCls .x-grid-checkcolumn-checked:before {
 content:"\f05d"
}

.myCls .x-grid-checkcolumn:before {
 content:"\f05c"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is not extJS solution, but it can be achieved by CSS and some custom icons (here with FontAwesome).
What is done here is, that you hide default checkbox and display icon instead. As FontAwesome does not have icon in frame for X by default, I've created a border there.
Only drawback is, that you can't use `<label><input></label>`

```css
@import url(//opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.3/font-awesome.min.css);

h1 { font-size: 1.5em; }
label { font-size: 24px; }
div { 
  width: 175px; 
  margin-left: 20px;
}

input[type=checkbox] { display:none; }

input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25%;
  line-height: 17px;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  content: "\f00d";
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  content: "\f00c";
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1>
<div>
  <input id="box1" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="box1">Unchecked</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="box2" type="checkbox" checked />
  <label for="box2">Checked</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for downvoting! explanation is more than welcome!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: "i need check sign (✔) on checked and wrong sign (x) on unchecked." .. oh, really? only because it's not extJS but CSS?!

Comment: Really. It's entirely reasonable to infer that the OP is referring to the Ext checkbox component. Why else would they tag the question as such?